# How to execute kubectl command in a cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two clusters

```
NAME                   LOCATION        MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP      MACHINE_TYPE   NODE_VERSION    NUM_NODES  STATUS
cassandra-cluster      europe-west4-a  1.14.10-gke.36  xx.90.xx.31    n1-standard-1  1.14.10-gke.36  3          RUNNING
codingjediweb-cluster  europe-west4-a  1.14.10-gke.36  uu.90.uu.182  n1-standard-1  1.14.10-gke.36  2          RUNNING
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$
```

I want to run the following command on cassandra-cluster. How do I make cassandra-cluster my current context?

I am getting error

```
CASS_USER=$(kubectl --cluster gke_copper-frame-262317_europe-west4-a_cassandra-cluster get secret cluster1-superuser -o json | jq -r '.data.username' | base64 --decode)kubectl
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "cluster1-superuser" not found
```

I tried this but it failed.

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl config use-context cassandra-cluster 
error: no context exists with the name: "cassandra-cluster"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work with multiple cluster setting the correct context, as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration):

```yaml
kubectl config get-contexts                          # display list of contexts 
kubectl config current-context                       # display the current-context
kubectl config use-context my-cluster-name           # set the default context to my-cluster-name
```

When working with multilples cluster, you always need to know in what cluster you are performing commands, to make it easy,you can use [this bash script](https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1) to show in you `$PS1` the current context and namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set get contexts and then set the context as follow

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                                                           CLUSTER                                                        AUTHINFO                                                       NAMESPACE
          gke_copper-frame-262317_europe-west4-a_cassandra-cluster       gke_copper-frame-262317_europe-west4-a_cassandra-cluster       gke_copper-frame-262317_europe-west4-a_cassandra-cluster   
*         gke_copper-frame-262317_europe-west4-a_codingjediweb-cluster   gke_copper-frame-262317_europe-west4-a_codingjediweb-cluster   gke_copper-frame-262317_europe-west4-a_codingjediweb-cluster
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl config use-context gke_copper-frame-262317_europe-west4-a_codingjediweb-cluster
```